# Find the differential equation of a control system via its block diagram

Tags: simulation, control-system, modeling, simulink, block-diagram

I have this block diagram:

[image]

I need to find the differential equation that represents the behavior of the control system, but I don't know what to do with the inner and outer feedback. I tried to simplify the diagram, without success.

Comment: If you'll show what you have done then people will be able to point out the exact place where the mistake is. Otherwise, nobody knows what/who/where.

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint to get you started: -

[image]

> *I tried to simplify the diagram, without success*

Sometimes you have to make things appear more complex to realize the simplicity.